# How to check lapsed time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, time

i m getting like startTime 13:30:00 endTime 14:15:00 (24 hour format) by dragging on html table cell.
    In hiddenfield i am storing values starttime and endtime

```
                var hidStartTime=13:30:00;
                var hidEndTime=14:15:00;
```

i have to check if users startime and endtime is past compare to current client machine time then have to generate alert("You can not allow to fix appointment for past time.");
How do i check

```
            var todaysDate = new Date();
            var currentHour = todaysDate.getHours();
            var currentMinutes = todaysDate.getMinutes();

            if (currentHour < endTimeHour)
            {
                alert("You can not allow to fix appointment for past time.");
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: i have to check if users startime and endtime is past compare to current client machine time then have to generate alert"";

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the date is going to be today, you can create Date objects with the start and end times, and then compare them with the current date, like so.

```
var currDate  = new Date();
var startDate = setTime(hidStartTime);
var endDate   = setTime(hidEndTime);

// given an input string of format "hh:mm:ss", returns a date object with 
// the same day as today, but the given time.
function setTime(timeStr) {
    var dateObj = new Date();          // assuming date is today
    var timeArr = timeStr.split(':');  // to access hour/minute/second

    var hour    = timeArr[0]; 
    var minute  = timeArr[1];
    var second  = timeArr[2];

    dateObj.setHours(hour);
    dateObj.setMinutes(minute);
    dateObj.setSeconds(second);
    return dateObj;
}

// now we can subtract them (subtracting two Date objects gives you their 
// difference in milliseconds)
if (currDate - startDate < 0 || currDate - endDate < 0) {
    alert("Unfortunately, you can't schedule a meeting in the past. 
             We apologize for the inconvenience.");
}
```

Comment: Achal: var startDate = setTime(hidStartTime);
var endDate   = setTime(hidEndTime);
startDate and endDate i m getting todays date

Comment: Today's date, or today's date *and* time? It should return the same "date" as today, but with different times.

Comment: see in hidStartTime=09:15:00 hidEndTime=10:00:00 so now current time is 03:15:00 so definately have to generate alert but it doesnt

Comment: Achal i have to check only lapsed time not date

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand why that should generate an alert. Both the start and end times are in the future (9>3 and 10>3) assuming the date is the same. Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Achal if i wrong then u also check in ur machine not get alert even taking hardcode value

Comment: @John: Instead of var hidStartTime=13:30:00 try putting quotes like: var hidStartTime="13:30:00"

Comment: I tried var time1 = setTime("13:30:00"); var time2= setTime("13:31:00");  You can check that this is working correctly by console.log(time1.toString()) and console.log(time2.toString()) - both have different values of time.  It looks correct.  You can then test that (time1 < time2) is true.

Comment: `Achal i have to check only lapsed time not date`  @John Since we are using Javascript's `Date` object for comparison, even though you are only interested in time, the date (dd-mm-yyyy) also needs to be set to any value as long as they are equal.

Comment: Instead of var hidStartTime="13:30:00" it would be good if you can get a date time string in hidStartTime like: var hidStartTime="Thu, 05 Jul 2012 15:20:06 GMT".  If this is possible it will simplify the problem and also make it more reliable because you have timezone info.

Comment: If the date part is confusion, another solution is to convert "13:30:00" into seconds without using Javascript Date object. Example: var hidStartTime="13:30:00"; var arr = "13:30:00".split(":"); var hidStartSecs = arr[0]*3600 + arr[1]*60 + arr[2]*1;

Answer (score 0):

You can compare 2 Date objects like this:

```
// Get current date on the client machine
var currentDateTime = new Date(); // "Thu, 05 Jul 2012 08:05:57 GMT"

// Now if you have a date string of 8:30 on the same day
var endDateTime = Date.parse("Thu, 05 Jul 2012 08:30:00 GMT");

if (currentDateTime > endDateTime) {
  alert("...");
}
```

The tough part might be to compose the date string to a format which can be understood by the function Date.parse()

Comment: kayo:hav to compare this time var hidStartTime=13:30:00;
                var hidEndTime=14:15:00;  with current machine time

Comment: ok. Looks like Achal has posted the right answer. Also note that if someone accesses the website from a different timezone, then it won't give correct results.

Comment: Would be good if the hidden field includes Timezone info and an absolute time such as "Thu, 05 Jul 2012 08:30:00 GMT". The server side  should be generate such a string.

Comment: kayo in achal answer var startDate = setTime(hidStartTime); var endDate = setTime(hidEndTime); startDate and endDate i m getting todays date